# Obter valores do WebSQL quando carregar a página através do Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, front-end, localstorage, websql

Quando carrego a página mesmo a função **getChamadasFromDay()** iniciando apos o carregamento as variaveis total_time e total_chamadas continuam com o valor zero.
reparem que a variavel **total_time** e **total_chamadas** estão recebendo valores mas por algum motivo continuam como **0 Zero**.
Se efetuar um `console.log(results.row.item(i).d_time)` ele imprime os valores no console.

***Necessito que quando carregar a página obtenha todos os valores do WEBSQL e efetue um calculo para ser informado na tela.***

```js
var total_time   = 0;
var total_chamadas  = 0;

window.addEventListener('load',function(){initDB()},false);


function initDB(){
  db = openDatabase (database_name, database_version, database_description, database_size);
  if(!db){
   alert('Erro Navegador nao possui suporte ao WebSQL.')
  }
  else{
   getChamadasFromDay();
  }
 }
```

```js
function getChamadasFromDay(){
 db.transaction (function (tx) {
     tx.executeSql ('SELECT * FROM chamadas WHERE d_day=? AND d_month=? AND d_year=?', [
       data.getDate(),
    data.getMonth(),
    data.getFullYear()
      ], function (tx, results) {
       var len = results.rows.length;
       for (i = 0; i <len; i ++) {
        total_time += parseInt(results.rows.item(i).d_time);
        total_chamadas++;
       }
    }, null);
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Experimente fazer desta forma:

```
function getChamadasFromDay() {

    db.transaction (function (tx) {

         var total_time     = 0;
         var total_chamadas = 0;

         tx.executeSql ('SELECT *
                        FROM  chamadas
                        WHERE d_day=?
                        AND   d_month=?
                        AND   d_year=?',
               [
                data.getDate(),
                data.getMonth() + 1, //em javascript: janeiro é 0
                data.getFullYear()
               ], function (tx, results) {
                     for (var i in results.rows) {
                         total_time    += parseInt(results.rows.item[i].d_time);
                         total_chamadas++;
                     }
                  }, null);
    });
}
```